# Bash array parameter expansion within parameter name: bad substitution

Tags: bash, shell, variables, recursion, parameters

I wrote a script in which I want the user to input a directory or many directories and each is checked for something unimportant to this discussion. All interior directories are also checked up to a specified depth.

While I can declare the array `Directories0` (the input directories) to start, I cannot refer to it in any way... result: bad substitution. Obviously, `Directories1` would be depth=1, `Directories2` is depth=2, and so on...

**Below is a snippet of code:**

```
let Recurse=4               ## say... variable value ##
[ "$Recurse" ] && let MaxDepth="$Recurse" || let MaxDepth=0
declare -i depth=0

IFS=$'\n'
## declare -a Directories${depth}=("${@}")      ##  <—— doesn't work
## declare -a Directories${depth}="("${@}")"        ##  <—— works if the brackets only are quoted...
## declare -a Directories${depth}=\("${@}"\)        ##  <—— ... or escaped
declare -a "Directories${depth}=("${@}")"
IFS=$' \t\n'

## Nested loop, depth counter increases for each directory depth. I want to stop at a specific depth which is entered as an option ##
for (( depth = 0; depth <= MaxDepth; depth++ )); do                  ## MaxDepth is entered as option ##
    until [ -z "${Directories${depth}[*]}" ]; do                       ## ***** bad substitution error ***** ##
        declare input="$(follow "${Directories${depth}[0]}")"       ## follow is a script that resolves symlinks and Finder aliases ##
        CheckDirectory "${input%/}/"                                  ## check directory ##
        case $? in

        ## Tests passed ##
        0)  if [[ "$Recurse" && "$depth" -lt "$MaxDepth" ]]; then
                IFS=$'\n'
                ## get ready to check sub-directories ##
                declare -a Directories$(( depth + 1 ))="("${Directories$(( depth + 1 ))[@]}" $(find -P "${Directories${depth}[0]}" -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec follow '{}' \;))"
                IFS=$' \t\n'
            fi
            true;;

        ## Tests failed ##
        *)  false;;
        esac
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && unset Directories${depth}[0] || exit 1             ## if test fails, exit, if succeeds, move on to next directory ##
        declare -a Directories${depth}="("${Directories${depth}[@]}")"      ## re-shuffle the array to get rid of null value at index 0 ##
        (( element++ ))
    done
done
```

**Below is a simplified version in case you don't want to go through the code above, this is the crux of the problem:**

```
depth=2
declare -a "Directories${depth}=(yo man ma me mo)"
echo "${Directories${depth}[4]}"
    > -bash: ${Directories${depth}[4]}: bad substitution
echo "${Directories2[4]}"
    > mo
```

Solutions, anyone?

Answer (score 4):

You need a literal variable name inside the `${}` construct. If you want to refer to a variable whose name is determined at runtime, you need to explicitly go through a level of indirection.

```
name="Directories${depth}[4]"
echo ${!name}
```

This doesn't help for assignments. As long as you're assigning in the current scope (and not in an encompassing scope), you can make computed assignments with the `typeset` built-in. However, be careful: bash has a heuristic which makes it transform assignments that look like the array assignment syntax into array assignments. This means the code below is ok if the element is going to store an absolute file name (which always begins with a `/`) but not if it is going to store an arbitrary file name (which could be something like `(foo)`).

```
typeset "Directories${depth}[4]=new value"
```

It is, alternatively, possible to perform assignments to a variable whose name is determined at runtime with any shell by using `eval`. This has the advantage of working in any shell, not just bash. You need to be very careful, though: it's hard to get the quoting right. It's best to make the argument of `eval` do as little as possible. Use a temporary variable to obtain store the value.

```
eval "tmp=\${Directories${depth}[4]}"
echo "$tmp"
tmp="new value"
eval "Directories${depth}[4]=\$tmp"
```

Comment: Ok, after blowing up my code (now >3x larger... and much slower to boot), I turned all my arrays into regular parameter assignments through many, many loops. A lot of unnecessary code. both `eval` and indirect referencing are great but do dick all for arrays, both assignment and referrals. Is there **NO WAY** to deal with array assignments all at once? Like: `typeset -a Directories${depth}=("${Array[@]}")`? or, what I need: `typeset -a Directories${depth}=("${Directories${depth}[@]}")` using `eval`? indirect referencing? some other trick? Perhaps another language? perl? c? php?

Comment: @Aesthir Indeed, I think Perl is what you're looking for.

Comment: _Thank you Giles_ for your well thought out answer that cleary took more than a minute to type up.  I have studied it for quite some time and attempted many (100s) of quick tests with mostly one-liners, modifying syntax or approaching the problem from different angles... but still I'm stuck. If Perl can offer a solution, I wouldn't know. Beyone Perl regex, I don't know the first thing about Perl (usage/syntax/commands/etc). **Can you offer a bit of Perl code** to, say, re-index the array as in the 4th line from the bottom in my script? I'm sure it'll be a one-liner...

Comment: @Aesthir Perl started out as shell and awk tied into one, and has evolved a lot since then. It has decent support for nested data structures, which is what you're after here (directories indexed by depth and breadth). I don't know what “re-index the array” means, but the equivalent to the assignment here would be `$Directories[$depth][4] = "new value"` if changing an existing element, or `push @{$Directories[$depth]}, "new value"` to append to the end of an existing array.

Comment: By "re-index the array" I mean how to get this line in the original script above (4th from bottom) to work with bash _or_ Perl, doesn't matter: **`declare -a Directories${depth}="("${Directories${depth}[@]}")"`**  Basically, here's the command I wish to run: `typeset -a Directories0=("${Directories0[@]}")` ... how do I get that to work (any language)?

Answer (score 1):

Use eval, this works:

```
eval echo \${Directories${depth}[4]}

mo
```

Comment: ya, ok the simple example works, no spaces., but this simple example is nowhere to be found in my code, it was just used to illustrate my problem. The meat of the problem is in the code, if you don't want to get the whole thing working, then **focus on the 4th line from the bottom and get that working without looping through every element using `eval`**. Remember, the values are not simply "mo", but long lines with spaces and Unicode characters way beyone basic Latin. I put foreward the notion that `eval` does **not** work, but maybe I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try eval

```
#!/bin/bash
depth=2
declare -a "Directories${depth}=(yo man ma me mo)"
eval echo "\${Directories${depth}[4]}"
echo "${Directories2[4]}"
```

Comment: The problem with `eval` is I can't seem to do **anything with *arrays***. `eval` breaks up elements containing spaces no matter what the IFS is set to. I tried and tried, but to no avail... Here's a challenge, try to get the code that I posted as a question to work using `eval`... The only thing I can think of is for looping through every element every time I wish to use eval. For starters, ***without looping*, use `eval` to get the 4th line from the bottom to work (re-shuffle). If `eval` really *can* do this, I'm sure it'll be an easy one-liner.**

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
declare -a Directories${depth}="( yo man ma me mo )"
```

works (and without eval, btw). To access the value, use the ${!} syntax:

```
temp=Directories$depth[@]
echo ${!temp}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a (belated) answer to what was being asked? (The question is not as clear as the asker believes, I feel....)

```
#!/bin/bash

for depth in {0..5}
do
  var_value=(yo man ma me mo "last value")
  var_name="directories${depth}"
  eval "${var_name}=\"${var_value[${depth}]}\""

  value="directories${depth}"
  printf "directories{$depth} = ${!value}"

  [ $depth -eq 0 ] && printf "  \t directories0=$directories0\n"
  [ $depth -eq 1 ] && printf "  \t directories1=$directories1\n"
  [ $depth -eq 2 ] && printf "  \t directories2=$directories2\n"
  [ $depth -eq 3 ] && printf "  \t directories3=$directories3\n"
  [ $depth -eq 4 ] && printf "  \t directories4=$directories4\n"
  [ $depth -eq 5 ] && printf "  \t directories5=$directories5\n"
done
```

Which produces:

```
directories{0} = yo      directories0=yo
directories{1} = man     directories1=man
directories{2} = ma      directories2=ma
directories{3} = me      directories3=me
directories{4} = mo      directories4=mo
directories{5} = last value      directories5=last value
```

The main point being that if a variable name consists of another variable, how does one assign a value to it.  E.g., if setting "foobar=value" is the normal way to set a variable to a value, then what if x=foo and y=bar, how does one set "${x}${y}=value" => e.g.:

```
  foobar=test
  echo $foobar
  > test

  x=foo
  y=bar
  eval "export ${x}${y}=\"value\""
  echo $foobar
  > value
```

If I've misunderstood the question, well, I'm not terribly surprised :-)